# Vim: initially close two top-most marker-fold levels

Tags: vim, folding

For C code I like to use marker folding and marker-blocks like the following to structure the code inside of functions.

```
int main()
{
    /* CODE BLOCK { */
    ....
    /* } */
}
```

How can I initially close the two top-most fold levels? So only the function bodies and the marker-blocks are closed but not the code inside?
So something like the inverse of `set foldlevel=2`.

I know of foldnestmax which, however, does only work for indent- and syntax-folding and as it sets a maximal level it does not allow manual folding of lower-level folds afterwards.

**Update:**
For clarification, when opening the file I'd like to see

```
int main()----------------------------
```

When opening this fold it should look like

```
int main()
{
    /* CODE BLOCK { */----------------
}
```

And finally after opening this fold level everything inside, i.e. the `...`, should be fully opened.

Comment: I'm confused. What do you want to display? Do you want to hide from "int main" to "CODE BLOCK", SHOW the "...", and then hide the rest?